# XML Illegal Characters in path using XPathDocument to do XSL Transform in C#

Tags: c#, xml, string, xslt, xpath

I have an XML in a `string` that I need to actually transform to `html` using an `xsl`.

I do the transform with `XslCompiledTransform`. In order for this to work, I am parsing the string that contains the XML to XML using `XPathDocument`.

However if I try to parse the `string` straight to the `XPathDocument`, then I get the error:

> Illegal Characters in path.

So I had to include a `StringReader` in order to be able to parse the string to the `XPathDocument`. (Using the solutions in the posts I linked below.)

Here is my step by step procedure:

1. The `string` is retrieved from SDL Trados Studio and it depends on the XML that is being worked on (how it was originally created and loaded for translations) the `string` sometimes has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) sometimes not. The 'xml' is actually parsed from the segments of the source and target text and the structure element. The textual elements are escaped for xml and the markup and text is joined in one `string`. (My separate post on the removal of the BOM is [C# XPathDocument parsing string to XML with BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222980/c-sharp-xpathdocument-parsing-string-to-xml-with-bom).)
2. The the `string` is then parsed into an `XPathDocument` using a `StringReader`.
3. The transform is done with the `XslCompiledTransform`, using a `StringBuilder` and a `StringWriter`.
4. Transformed xml (now html) is saved to a file.

Here is my code:

```
//Recreate XML file using an extractor returns a string array
string strSourceXML = String.Join("", extractor.TextSrc);

//strip BOM
strSourceXML = strSourceXML.Substring(strSourceXML.IndexOf("<?"));

//Transform XML with the preview XSL
var xSourceDoc = new XPathDocument(strSourceXML);

//Load XSL
var xTr = new XslCompiledTransform();
var xslt = Settings.GetValue("WordPreview", "XSLTpath", "");
xTr.Load(xslt);

//Parse XML string
dynamic xSourceDoc;
using (StringReader s = new StringReader(strSourceXML))
{
    xSourceDoc = new XPathDocument(s);
}

//Transform the XML
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter swSource = new StringWriter(sb1);
xTr.Transform(xSourceDoc, null, swSource);

//Transformed file saved to the disk
string tmpSourceDoc = Path.GetTempFileName();

System.IO.StreamWriter writer1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(tmpSourceDoc, false, Encoding.Unicode);
writer1.Write(sb1.ToString());
writer1.Close();
```

My question is: Is there a simpler way to solve it? Any suggestions to transform the string straight using the XSLT? Or if not, is there a direct way to parse a string to the XPathDocument?

I have searched over many posts on Stack Overflow such as these:

- [XML Illegal Characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057938/xml-illegal-characters-in-path)
- [Illegal characters in path error while parsing XML in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374729/illegal-characters-in-path-error-while-parsing-xml-in-c-sharp)
- [Illegal characters in path when loading a string with XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586838/illegal-characters-in-path-when-loading-a-string-with-xdocument)

But none of them give me the solution to do this simpler. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use something like this: `XmlDocumentInstance.LoadXml(yourString);`  Read more here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v%3Dvs.110).aspx

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev What code lines would I need to replace then? Can you make this comment into an answer with some code lines?

Comment: Just a look at the provided msdn link will help you -- there is a code example. `LoadXml()` produces the wanted `XmlDocument` instance from your string. Then you can transform that `XmlDocument` in the usual way.

Comment: I did of course! But it was not telling me about the transform this is why I asked. I used the `XPathDocument` because that's the type that worked with the transform. But I may have done some other mistake. So you say that the `XslCompiledTransform` takes the `XmlDocument` as well?

Comment: Yes. Read this. XmlDocument implements IXpathNavigable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163435(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need the intermediate `StringBuilder` and `StringWriter`.
`XsltCompiledTransform` instance can immediately writes to the stream on disk.

```
string strSourceXML = string.Concat(extractor.TextSrc);

strSourceXML = strSourceXML.Substring(strSourceXML.IndexOf("<?"));

var xTr = new XslCompiledTransform();
var xslt = Settings.GetValue("WordPreview", "XSLTpath", "");
xTr.Load(xslt);

string tmpSourceDoc = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var reader = new StringReader(strSourceXML))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tmpSourceDoc, false, Encoding.Unicode))
{
    var xSourceDoc = new XPathDocument(reader);
    xTr.Transform(xSourceDoc, null, writer);
}
```

Comment: The two `using`s would the second one need to be put into the block of the first one? like `using () {using() { //code }}`?

Comment: One thing though, I need the StringWriter because I need too replace the header of the HTML to make it a Word doc, my earlier post on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37036506/6201755

Comment: @ib11 - A few `using` in a row is a short form.
I would made the necessary html headers in the xsl transformation.

Comment: OK on using, thanks. Hmm, html headers in the transform... Dah... why did I not think of this? :S Well let's see...